# Android Hierarchy viewer is not showing timings for rendering

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm having some performance problems with my application and I've found [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) for helping me.

The problem is that when I execute Hierarchy viewer, I always have `n/a as Measure`, Layout and Draw time for each component of the view.

I'm using Android 3.2 in my virtual device.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I add a capture of the Hierarchy Viewer output:
[image: Hierarchy Viewer example]

When I use the Hierarchy viewer with the initial activity (a very simple activity), it works perfectly. But when i used this activity, I can't see the times for drawing each component.

Comment: Have you tried other Android versions in the emulator? 3.2 is a bit of an odd choice, since there fairly few devices running that version.

Comment: Does it happen only in your app or also on the stock apps in your emulator?

Comment: What is your minimum target sdk version? NOT the device version.

Answer (score 12):

To see the three measures select your root view and click this button [image: show measures button]. Its description is *"Obtain layout times for tree rooted at selected node"*. The button has to be placed on the top of the Hierarchy viewer.

Answer (score 5):

Android  hierarchy viewer is working on Android 2.3 and onwards. It does not matter what your device os version is. Your target api version should be 2.3 or higher. In that case you can change the min version in project properties.

If you want to optimize your layout you need to do several things. [This article](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-tools-leveraging-the-hierarchy-viewer-for-ui-profiling/) explain how to optimize and the areas you should concern more.

Comment: Min Target API is 10 (2.3). I've edited my question. Take a look

Comment: It is odd and if I were you I would try 
1) recreating with higher sdk version 
2) try with fresh and complete sdk installation.

Answer (score 4):

Click  where the arrows are in this pic

That is, the root node, and then the "profile node" button in the top right.

Then click individual nodes and it shows timings rather than n/a

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be sub effect of [hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) that comes from Android 3.0.
But without any more details (perhaps a code samples), it will be hard to tell.

Comment: I've tried with an simply code and it has worked, but with my applicación didn't. Maybe it doesn't work with very complex layouts.